# recyclerview onScrollListener not working correctly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener

I've got a `recyclerView` within a `pull to refresh layout`.
I've added an `onScrollListener` to keep track of the total vertical movement by adding/subtracting the `delta Y (dy)` to a variable named `totalScrolled`.
And if the `recyclerview` is scrolled fully to the top `totalScrolled` should be 0 and a view should be visible.

Problem only is that somehow there is a bug and the `scroll listener` is not accurate in telling me how much the list has `scrolled`. After scrolling down and back up again through my many items list somehow the `totalScrolled` doesn't return to 0.

Anyone ran into this issue as well and knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the dy from the scrollListener's onScrolled callback to keep track of the total vertical scroll which is inaccurate I use a function from the recyclerView itself - **RecyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset()** - which accurately keeps track of how many pixels the recyclerView has scrolled.

My code looks something like this:

```
    home_screen_recycler.addOnScrollListener(object: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

            val scrollOffset = home_screen_recycler.computeVerticalScrollOffset()

            presenter.onListScrolled(scrollOffset)
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project I use this logic.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if (arrayList.size() == 0)
                return;
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                int itemPosition = mLinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                if (itemPosition == (arrayList.size() - 1)) {
                    // here you can fetch new data from server.
                }
            }
        }
    });
```